# Confirmation with Spinner

Tags: java, android, dialog, spinner

The code below allows the user to chose A,B,C or D. I want the code to have a popup confirmation when D is selected, the confirmation asking Yes to continue or No to return.

Is this possible?

```
Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String[] items = new String[]{"A","B", "C", "D"};
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);    

dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    /**
    * Called when a new item is selected (in the Spinner)
    */
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id)
    {


    } 
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

As Joe C said, Yes.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id){
    String selected = items[id]
    if(selected.equals("D")){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Confirmation");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", null);
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", null);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

And you should add a listener where is "null"...

Comment: Could I ask if you would have the pop up code when selected.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: i edited, now there is the popup message asking for confirmation

Comment: Yes Joe, I do know it. But when I was learned, I needed some people answering like I did, and I didn't gave all, in my case he would need to search about the listener herself...

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AlertDialog once an Item is selected. Here is the code.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id)
{
    String selected = items[id]
    if(selected.equals("D")){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle("Are you sure?")
      .setMessage("If you go back you will loose any changes.")
      .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
          // doSomething();
          dialog.dismiss();
      })
    .setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
    .show();
    }
}
```

Change the doSomething() method with your desired code on yes button press. Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: The internet seems to be full of angry people @JoeC

Comment: I'm in a very good mood this evening, actually @SondraWilliams